# Poisson kernel for half disc

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to derive the Poisson kernel for half disc $\Omega = D(0,1) \cap \{ z \in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Im} z > 0 \}$. Suppose we have the BVP
$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\Delta u =0 \qquad & \text{in } \Omega \\
u= \phi \qquad & \text{on } \partial \Omega
\end{array} \right. $$
where $\phi$ is continuous and real-valued.
I know that the composition of
$$ z \mapsto \frac{2z}{z^2+1}, \qquad \text{and} \qquad z \mapsto \frac{z-i}{z+i}$$ is a conformal map from $\Omega$ onto $D(0,1)$. If you compute this, $f: \Omega \rightarrow D(0,1)$ given by
$$ f(z) = \frac{2z - i (z^2+1)}{2z + i (z^2+1)}$$
is a biholomorphism.
I tried to apply Poisson integral formula for $D(0,1)$ on the following BVP:

$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\Delta (u \circ f^{-1}) =0 \qquad & \text{in } D(0,1) \\
u \circ f^{-1}= \phi \circ f^{-1} \qquad & \text{on }  \partial D(0,1)
\end{array} \right. $$

Then using change of variables,
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &&u (\tilde{\omega}) \\
&=&u \circ f^{-1}(z) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \phi(f^{-1}(e^{i\theta})) \frac{1-|z|^2}{|z-e^{i \theta}|^2} d \theta \\
&=& \cdots \\
&=& \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\Omega} \phi(\eta) \frac{1 - |f(\tilde{\omega})|^2}{|f(\tilde{\omega}) - f(\eta)|^2} \frac{4 (1- \eta)^2}{4 \eta^2 + (\eta^2 + 1)^2} d \eta
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\tilde{\omega} = f^{-1}(z)$.

But this integral is too complicated and I have no idea to proceed from here. Any suggestions about my argument? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You argument should work but the calculations might be simpler with
the following lemma.

> **Lemma.** Let $z \in \Omega$. There exists only one biholomorphism from $\Omega$ onto $\mathbb{D}$ that sends $z$ on the origin given by
> $$ \forall w \in \Omega,\ f_z(w) = \frac{w-z}{1-w \bar{z}} \frac{1-w z}{w-\bar{z}}. $$
> Furthermore, the function $f_z$ admits a smooth extension to some neighbourhood of $\Omega$.

Now, we proceed as you suggested.
Let $u \in \mathrm{H}(\Omega)$ continuous on the boundary. Then
$$ \forall z \in \Omega,\ u(z) = (u \circ f_z^{-1})(0) = \int_0^{2\pi} (u \circ f_z^{-1})(e^{i\theta}) \frac{d\theta}{2\pi}.$$
Let us do the change of variable $\xi = f_z^{-1}(e^{i\theta})$ in the above integral. But
$$ d\xi = ie^{i \theta} (f_z^{-1})'(e^{i\theta}) d\theta = i \frac{f_z(\xi)}{f_z'(\xi)} d\theta.$$
Hence
$$ \forall z \in \Omega,\ u(z) = \int_{\partial \Omega} u(\xi) P(z, \xi) d\xi\ \mbox{ with }\ P_{\Omega}(z, \xi) = -\frac{i}{2\pi} \cdot \frac{f_z'(\xi)}{f_z(\xi)}. $$
Using the additive property of the logarithmic derivative, we got
$$ \frac{f'_z(\xi)}{f_z(\xi)} = \frac{1-\xi\bar{z}}{\xi-z} \frac{1-|z|^2}{(1-\xi\bar{z})^2} - \frac{1-\xi z}{\xi-\bar{z}} \frac{1-|z|^2}{(1-\xi z)^2} = \frac{1-|z|^2}{(\xi-z)(1-\xi \bar{z})} - \frac{1-|z|^2}{(\xi-\bar{z})(1-\xi z)}. $$
Thus, the Poisson kernel of the half-disk is given by
$$ P_{\Omega}(z, \xi) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\cdot \left\{\frac{1-|z|^2}{(\xi-z)(1-\xi \bar{z})} - \frac{1-|z|^2}{(\xi-\bar{z})(1-\xi z)}\right\}. $$

If you split the boundary of $\Omega$ in two parts, namely the semi-circle and the interval $(-1, 1)$, you can produce more explicit formulae. See
*Value Distribution of Meromorphic Functions* of Goldberg and Ostrovskii, page 3. For instance, the Poisson kernel along the semi-circle is given by
\begin{align} P_{\Omega}(z, \xi) d\xi &= P_{\Omega}(z, e^{i\theta}) ie^{i\theta} d\theta = \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1-|z|^2}{|z-e^{i\theta}|^2}d\theta - \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{1-|z|^2}{|\bar{z}-e^{i\theta}|^2}d\theta \\ &= P_{\mathbb{D}}(z, e^{i\theta}) d\theta- P_{\mathbb{D}}(\bar{z}, e^{i\theta})d\theta. \end{align}
This relation between the Poisson kernels of the disk and the half-disk is not uncanny as soon as you are familiar with the Schwarz reflection principle.

Comment: hmm... I didn't know such lemma! It seems very convenient since we can send any interior point to the origin. Thank you!

Comment: Such a result holds for any simply connected domain of the plane. The property is true for the unit disk and you can extend it to any simply connected domain using the Riemann's uniformization theorem. Of course, in the case of the half-disk $\Omega$, you can use your explicit conformal map between $\Omega$ and the unit disk to get the explicit expression in the lemma.